# Understanding theano shared variable. What does following simple loop do in Theano?

Tags: python, theano

I came across a snipped code that is somewhat similar to follows:

```
for tensor_var in list_of_tensor_vars:
    acc = theano.shared(tensor_var.get_value(borrow=False) * 0., borrow=True)
    # do some processing on acc
```

I am trying to understand what this loop is doing.
My interpretation is:
It creates `acc` shared variable initialized to zero and has a size of `tensor_var`.
But these `tensor_vars` in `list_of_tensor_vars` have different dimensions.
Then is it creating multiple `acc` shared variables or it only creates a single `acc` shared variable?
I want to understand the way it works so that I can implement the same logic in `TensorFlow`.